# Gitlab Enterprise and Atlassian Jira Integration - SSL Certificate Verify Error

Tags: ssl, gitlab, jira, integration

**We are using Gitlab Enterprise Server 12.7.5-ee and Atlassian Jira Server version v8.6.1**

Following the documentation from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html, and sifting through forums for in depth solutions, I still cannot get past the "**SSL Verify**" error, when attempting to save the integration settings

**Integration Error:**

```
Test failed. SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error. certificate verify failed (unspecified certificate verification error)
```

**Integration Settings used:**
[image]

**I have ensured that both servers have an open path to speak through port 443, via the AWS EC2 security group**

**I have exported the SSL Certificate used on the Jira server, and added the certificate to the following locations on the Gitlab Enterprise RHEL server:**

- /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/
- /etc/gitlab/ssl/
- /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs

The Jira certificate is a valid certificate, issued from DigiCert, and verified via 
**https://whatsmychaincert.com/**

We have also ensured that Gitlab Issue tracker is enabled, as that is a requirement for cross integration with Jira

I cannot determine if the issue is with the Gitlab server not knowing about, and trusting the Jira Certificate, or if the issue is with the Jira Certificate its self, or Gitlab in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab's [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/README.html#ssl-certificate-errors) has this to say about SSL certificate errors during integrations:

> When trying to integrate GitLab with services that are using self-signed certificates, it is very likely that SSL certificate errors will occur in different parts of the application, most likely Sidekiq.
>
> There are two approaches you can take to solve this:
>
> Add the root certificate to the trusted chain of the OS.
>   1. If using Omnibus, you can add the certificate to GitLab’s trusted certificates.
>
> 2. It looks from the screenshot like there is a "Save Anyway" link. Does that work?

It has more detail about 1 and 2, if you want to try that.  I know you're not using a self-signed certificate, but maybe this info will be helpful.

See also https://blog.engineyard.com/ruby-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed which suggests a few possible causes / fixes.  But I'd go with the GitLab docs first!